# How $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]{x}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}\big(\pi/2+\ln{\beta}\big)$

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse, trigonometric-integrals

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan\left(x\right)}{1 + x}
\,\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[{\large 4}]{x}} =
\frac{\pi}{\,\sqrt{\,{2}\,}\,}
\left[{\pi \over 2} + \ln\left(\,{\beta}\,\right)\right]
$$
$$
\mbox{Find the value of}\quad
\beta^{4} - 28\beta^{3} + 70\beta^{2} - 28\beta.
$$
How to do this question ?. I tried conventional approaches such as substituting $x$ with $1/t^{2}$ but none of them is yielding an answer.

Comment: Okay. Can you find $\int \dfrac{1}{(1+x)x^{1/4}}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @openspace Yes. By substituting x with $t^4$

Comment: @Wood then do integration by parts

Comment: @openspace Wouldn't it become too complicated?

Comment: [Here](   https://brilliant.org/problems/an-arctan-integral-via-a-quartic-equation/?ref_id=1585875)   is the original problem posted by author of the problem.

Comment: @Wood maybe there is a more simple approach. Try this: $I(a) = \int \arctan (ax)/((1+x)x^{1/4}$. Then differentiate with respect to a, maybe it gives you something easier.

Answer (score 5):

Write

\begin{align*}
I
:= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan x}{(x+1)x^{1/4}} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3/4}}{(x+1)(t^2x^2+1)} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

The inner integral can be computed via a standard technique involving the contour integration along the keyhole contour. Indeed, denoting by $\operatorname{Log}$ the complex logarithm with the branch cut $[0,\infty)$ and writing

$$ f(z) = \frac{\exp\left(\frac{3}{4}\operatorname{Log}(z)\right)}{(z+1)(t^2z^2+1)}, $$

we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3/4}}{(x+1)(t^2x^2+1)} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \frac{2\pi i}{1 - e^{3\pi i/2}} \left(
\underset{z=-1}{\mathrm{Res}} \, f(z)
+ \underset{z=i/t}{\mathrm{Res}} \, f(z)
+ \underset{z=-i/t}{\mathrm{Res}} \, f(z) \right) \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{\sin(3\pi/4)} \left( \frac{1}{t^2+1} + \frac{e^{-3i\pi/8}}{2(it-1)t^{3/4}} + \frac{e^{3i\pi/8}}{2(-it-1)t^{3/4}} \right).
\end{align*}

Now by noting that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\omega \, \mathrm{d}t}{(\omega^4 t - 1)t^{3/4}}
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\omega \, \mathrm{d}u}{(\omega u)^4 - 1}
= -2\arctan(\omega) + \log\left(\frac{1-\omega}{1+\omega}\right) $$

holds for any complex $\omega$ avoiding the branch cuts $\cup_{k=0}^{3} i^k [1,\infty)$, the original integral reduces to

\begin{align*}
I
&= - \pi \sqrt{2} \biggl( \frac{\pi}{4} - \arctan(e^{3i\pi/8}) - \arctan(e^{-3i\pi/8}) \\
&\hspace{5em} + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1-e^{3i\pi/8}}{1+e^{3i\pi/8}}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1-e^{-3i\pi/8}}{1+e^{-3i\pi/8}}\right) \biggr) \\
&= - \pi \sqrt{2} \left( \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{2} + \log\tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{16}\right) \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\log\tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{16}\right) \right).
\end{align*}

Here, the second line follows from the identities $\arctan z+\arctan(1/z) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0$ and $\frac{1-e^{i\theta}}{1+e^{i\theta}}=-i\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$. This shows that

$$ \beta = \cot^2\left(\frac{3\pi}{16}\right). $$

Finally, using the observation that

$$ X = \beta + \beta^{-1} = \frac{4}{\sin^2(3\pi/8)} -2 = 14 - 8\sqrt{2} $$

is a zero of the equation $X^2 - 28X + 68 = 0$, we get

$$ \beta^4 - 28\beta^3 + 70\beta^2 - 28\beta + 1 = 0, $$

and therefore the answer is $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is proposed by sir Srinivasa Raghava in Romanian maths magazine and in Brilliant.org too.

here is the link:

https://brilliant.org/problems/an-arctan-integral-via-a-quartic-equation/?ref_id=1585875

Comment: I have a friend named Shivam Sharma with the same picture in your profile and he said that this profile is not his. Why are you stealing people's identities ? Too shy to make your own profile?

Comment: I agree with @Ali Shather claim here. Exactly the same has been said by Shivam Sharma to me  that the user is using photo and identities of his. It's better to make your own identity. Moreover, he added he isnt the MSE user.